# gradle Exec: could not find command

Tags: gradle, exec

Gradle exec: can not find the command on windows

```
task runTest(type: Exec) {
    workingDir "$buildDir/test"
    commandLine 'test.bat'
}
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "test.bat" (in directory 
"e:\foo\build\test"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file 
specified
```

But the test.bat is under the directory. I can go to the directory and run the command manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try:

```
task runTest(type: Exec) {
    workingDir "$buildDir/test"
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'test.bat'
}
```

as in the [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html).